# any gotchas when adding extra exterior ground

Tags: electrical, grounding

I have an old house with a single external ground: a thick multi strand silver colored wire bonded to rebar. Current electrical code in many jurisdictions ask for two ground rods, not less than 6 ft. from one another. I purchased a 4 ft. copper ground rod before later reading 8 feet would be better. I have bare 4 AWG copper wire. Would it help my system at all to bond the 4 AWG copper to the existing ground, run it above (or below) ground for 8+ feet, then bond to the new 4ft copper ground? Any gotchas to be aware of?

Comment: Your local regulations are the ones to go by, not the next door jurisdiction.  You might need to buy a second 8ft ground rod or just use the 4ft one.  You can use use the 4ft with the second 8ft one, since code deals with the minimums require.  Extra is usually okay.

Comment: OTOH, if that ground connects to rebar that then goes into your concrete footing, you might just have a Ufer ground and that _should be_ (local code dependent) sufficient.

Comment: Thank you. I added further comments below. I am concerned more about efficacy and safety rather than code compliance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *probably* can't do that. The ground wire to two ground rods is normally *one* wire, not a daisy-chain as you describe. As I understand it, the type of splice required to do a daisy-chain for the ground rod wire is far in excess of what most people would normally do, and therefore they use one wire to two rods.

However, a lot of these details vary by jurisdiction. In particular, in my area some counties require one wire to two rods, and others (or at least my specific jurisdiction as of late 2022 when I had the work done and inspected) required only *one* ground rod but *also* required a ground wire (separate wire) going to the copper water pipe as close as possible to where it comes into the building. If you have such a wire (in my case, the previous water pipe ground wire existed but was not anywhere near the entrance to the building, and I don't know if my electrician ever found a previous outdoor ground rod) then that may be sufficient.

If you are going to simply "add a 2nd ground rod" then I highly recommend installing a new ground wire to both the old and new rods. That will be code-compliant pretty much everywhere. Your main concern is safety/better ground, but that's the concern of code as well, and a single wire helps make sure that the second ground rod is always connected.

Comment: Thank you, and thanks to the others that have commented. My home is on a granite slab foundation, and there is no concrete or rebar-- just dirt. I wanted to add the extra copper rod only for better grounding, as opposed to code compliance. I am adding CSST to the system and bonding it to the main external ground. I wanted to add a second ground to better ensure safety, but remain confused from my reading whether the daisy chain approach would help, hurt, or not matter at all.

Comment: Thank you for the updated comment. Would installing a single wire between old a new rods require running that wire all the way into the house to the main panel, or just making sure that the new wire bonds to the existing ground wire plus both bars?

Comment: The concern (as I understand it) is that most ways of connecting wires are relatively speaking prone to come apart. This certainly happens with wire nuts and a lot of other connections. All the more so for a connection *outside*. The ground wire/ground rods are a very special situation: unlike typical branch circuit connections (where if a wire comes out the circuit stops working), you have *absolutely no way to know that ground isn't working* - as long as neutral and ground are bonded, you can't tell (without looking or testing) whether your ground rods are connected or not. The ground rods

Comment: hardly used at all *most* of the time, but very important in certain critical situations (e.g., nearby lightning strike). So the rules for connecting the ground rods are different from most other things: A single wire (I think 4 AWG typical, but minimum size depends on service size and/or local rules) going from the main panel to two rods, with no breaks/splices in the wire.